# Shorten SQL conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL with some conditions, for example:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN RIGHT(CAST(COLUMN_A as nvarchar(max)),1) = '.' THEN
  SUBSTRING (COLUMN_A, DATALENGTH(COLUMN_A) - 4, 4) ELSE
  SUBSTRING (COLUMN_A, DATALENGTH(COLUMN_A) - 3, 4) END AS COL_1
```

In the same select I have others check using the rule above and I have to repeat it all. I am looking for a way to do not repeat the rest of the code, something 
like:

```
CASE
  WHEN COL_1 LIKE 'AAAA' OR
  COL_1 LIKE 'BBBB' OR
  COL_1 LIKE 'CCCC' OR
  COL_1 LIKE 'DDDD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Code
```

Using the result of the COL_1 above to do the others checks. How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested SELECT command like this:

```
SELECT CASE
  WHEN x.COL_1 LIKE 'AAAA' OR
  x.COL_1 LIKE 'BBBB' OR
  x.COL_1 LIKE 'CCCC' OR
  x.COL_1 LIKE 'DDDD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Code
FROM (
SELECT
  CASE WHEN RIGHT(CAST(COLUMN_A as nvarchar(max)),1) = '.' THEN
  SUBSTRING (COLUMN_A, DATALENGTH(COLUMN_A) - 4, 4) ELSE
  SUBSTRING (COLUMN_A, DATALENGTH(COLUMN_A) - 3, 4) END AS COL_1
) x
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
        SELECT list_of_columns
             , CASE WHEN this=cool THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As computed_column
        FROM   ...
       ) As a_subquery
WHERE  computed_column = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

CASE Syntax should be like this:

```
CASE
  WHEN COL_1 LIKE 'AAAA' THEN 1 
  WHEN COL_1 LIKE 'BBBB' THEN 1 
  WHEN COL_1 LIKE 'CCCC' THEN 1 
  WHEN COL_1 LIKE 'DDDD' THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END AS Code
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn inside out, i.e. perform case in the substring:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING (COLUMN_A, DATALENGTH(COLUMN_A) -
    CASE WHEN RIGHT(CAST(COLUMN_A as nvarchar(max)),1) = '.' THEN then 4 else 3 end, 4) AS COL_1
```

and use IN for the different values, verify length if needed (LIKE and trailing blanks...)

```
CASE
  WHEN COL_1 IN ('AAAA','BBBB','CCCC','DDDD') and LENGTH(col_1) = 4 THEN 1
  ELSE 0 END AS Code
```